# Force fputcsv to enclose output in quotes

Tags: php, magento, csv, fputcsv

I found a couple of topics online about forcing to enclose the fputcsv output and found out that's not possible to do this. I need to enclose every output with quotes, because of some import requirements. Seperate words are working, but non-seperate works are not. I saw that there are a couple of workarounds, but I can't get them working. For example, I have this code:

> ```
> /**
>  * Writes the row(s) for the given order in the csv file.
>  * A row is added to the csv file for each ordered item. 
>  * 
>  * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order The order to write csv of
>  * @param $fp The file handle of the csv file
>  */
> protected function writeOrder($order, $fp) 
> {
>     $common = $this->getCommonOrderValues($order);
>     $orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
>     $itemInc = 0;
>     foreach ($orderItems as $item)
>     {
>         if (!$item->isDummy()) {
>             $record = array_merge($common, $this->getOrderItemValues($item, $order, ++$itemInc));
>             fputcsv($fp, $record, self::DELIMITER, self::ENCLOSURE);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Can you help me out to get this working?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817596/wrap-csv-values-generated-by-php-fputcsv-with

Answer (score 0):

Use the File_CSV package from PEAR at https://pear.php.net/package/File_CSV/

Your code would look something like this, which is obviously incomplete:

```
<?php
require 'File/CSV.php'; 
$csv_conf = array(
    'fields' => 3, 
    'crlf' => "\r\n", 
    'quote' => '"', 
    'sep' => ','
);

$common = $this->getCommonOrderValues($order);
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
$itemInc = 0;
foreach($orderItems as $item) {
    if (!$item->isDummy()) {
        $record = array_merge(
            $common, 
            $this->getOrderItemValues($item, $order, ++$itemInc)
        );
        $res = File_CSV::write($fileName, $record, $csv_conf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But with this, I have to install a PEAR package. Do you know if it's possible to do this without installing packages?

Comment: The File_CSV package is pretty much standalone - there is only one other package that it depends on (the File package). Download them and copy them inside your include_path somewhere and you should be fine.

Comment: I will give it a try in my test environment. Thank you! Will let you know how it works in a couple of days!

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use a code like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968232/1681144 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16942836/1681144?

Comment: I will give it a try soon. Thanks! I will let you know if it works for me.