# CSV comma delimited file from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a script to export a mysql table to a csv file.
It works great except that it exports it as a tab delimited file.
I need it to be comma delimited.
I tried INTO ONFILE but could not make it work.
So this is what I have now:

```
$fh = fopen(__DIR__ . '/Stock.csv', 'w');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY SKU");   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {          
    $num = mysql_num_fields($result) ;    
    $last = $num - 1;
    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {            
        fwrite($fh, $row[$i]);                       
        if ($i != $last) {
            fwrite($fh, "\t");
        }
    }                                                                 
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

How can I modify it so it becomes comma delimited?

Comment: Stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple MySQL statement - [SELECT + INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html), it will write CSV-like file with some options.

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'Stock.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
FROM table
ORDER BY SKU;
```

Comment: I've been trying to do this for the past hour but for some reason I can't make it work. I don't get any error but nothing gets written to the file.   `$Result = "SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/Stock.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
FROM table
ORDER BY SKU";  

mysql_query ($Result, $Link);`

Comment: Do you have FILE privilege? Or, maybe file with this name already exists.

Comment: `'/Stock.csv'`... in the filesystem root? No wonder, you probably don't have privileges

Comment: The file gets created but nothing gets written. How can I add privilege?

Comment: `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO '<user_name>'@'<host_name>';`

Comment: Actually I am not sure if it is a privilege problem as I am able to create the file: `fopen('/Stock.csv', 'w');`

Comment: From the documentation: ...so you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax

Comment: Yes I must have it because if you look at my original post I am able to write to file. It is just when I use the into outfile option you mentioned above that the file is empty.

Comment: Try to work with SELECT * INTO OUTFILE command, try another file name, maybe there was an error, try to execute from comand from another program.

Answer (score 0):

To ouput data from database to CSV you should use :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php
And to separate the data with comma you can use implode method:
[Wrap CSV values generated by PHP fputcsv() with " "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817596/wrap-csv-values-generated-by-php-fputcsv-with)
Please read both links carefully. I am sure that you will get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php

Use an array to insert a row into the csv file and set delimiter to ",".

```
$file = fopen("data.csv","w");
$a = array("value1","value2","value3");
fputcsv($file,$a,",");
```